# In a website, what is the value of og:title as opposed to a plain title element?

Tags: facebook-opengraph, rdfa, html-title

Why does the [Open Graph specification](http://ogp.me/) **requires**, as opposed to merely support, suggest or recommend, the use of `og:title` when in many cases it will be fully redundant with `<title></title>` from HTML, RDFa's superset?

What happens if, in the interests of brevity, normalisation, and a general dislike of bureaucratic duplication, one chooses to omit `og:title`?

Answer (score 4):

The `title` element and the `og:title` property typically don’t have the same content.

Both typically give the title of the main entity, but the `title` element [should provide context](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/76826/17633) (e.g., the site name) in addition.

(But even if they would have the same content, it might be preferable to allow consumers getting all OGP data by parsing just the RDFa, not also the HTML.)

#### Let’s take this question page as example

```html
<title>opengraph - In a website, what is the value of og:title as opposed to a plain title element? - Stack Overflow</title>
```

```html
<meta name="twitter:title" property="og:title" itemprop="title name" content="In a website, what is the value of og:title as opposed to a plain title element?" />
```

The `title` is:

> opengraph - In a website, what is the value of og:title as opposed to a plain title element? - Stack Overflow

The `og:title` is:

> In a website, what is the value of og:title as opposed to a plain title element?

#### What if they are the same?

Then you could provide the `og:title` property on the `title` element:

```html
<title property="og:title">…</title>
```

(But note that some OGP consumers might, unfortunately, not support anything else than `meta` elements.)